# WSO2 Developer Studio Backward compatability with Carbon studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have downloaded the new WS02 Developer Studio and Helios, but when I point it to an existing Carbon studio workspace, it does not recognize the carbon projects and their facets. Do we have to manually recreate the projects in Developer Studio and copy the xml files in?
I can create new wso2 projects correctly so it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Developer Studio 2.0.0 does not have the backward compatibility with Carbon Studio 1.0.14 as it contains lot of fundamental level changes around the project structuring, etc.

So you will not be able to use the C-App projects you created with Carbon Studio versions with Developer Studio.

We are planning on implementing a migration tool to migrate 1.0.x projects new project structure but we are unable to provide an exact timeline for the release of this tool.

Until then, the only possible option is to recreate the older projects manually with Developer Studio.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: This is really important to us, as remaking all of our projects will be a large amount of work. Could you please give an estimate of when the migration toll will be ready? Also as we have development support, could you confirm that you will still be supporting 1.0.14 projects , and that we will not have to upgrade to continue to receive support.